# hostname:port to access jupyter notebook in browser

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

At my university the machines are networked such that running something like "jupyter notebook --port 8000" on machine 'server' allows me to then access it by typing 'server:8000' in my browser window.

How would I go about recreating that on my home network? Specifically, I would like to be able to run jupyter notebook on my workstation, and browse to workstation:port from my laptop, rather than have to ssh in, forward ports, and then access it via localhost:port.

All machines are running linux (manjaro).

Comment: Just to be clear, both the workstation and laptop are running in the same (local) network? And the thing you are trying to achieve is to run jupyter on the workstation and access that on the laptop by specifying the hostname of the workstation and the port of the jupyter instance?

Comment: Yes correct, both are on my local network. I'm looking to cut out having to run ssh -L each time, and the potential for mistakes with things like jupyter running on workstation being accessed as localhost on laptop.

Comment: Ok sorry to ask but if the two machines can ping each other, then why couldnt you just run jupyter and access it over the LAN like `http://workstationhostname:8000/`?

Comment: Can ping. However firefox returns "Unable to connect    can’t establish a connection to the server at workstation:8888." As to why I cannot do that, well, that is the question I'm asking, and more specifically how to make it such that I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default jupyter will block this kind of remote access.

If you want to make it work you will have to first secure your notebook.

[Here's a link](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server) to the part of the documentation that you need.